# How to solve this following issue, SocketError "Failed to open TCP connection to server_name:xxxx (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, kong

I got this issue when I tried to access any endpoints from the main domain (running in UBUNTU 18.04 LTS app_server).
But, this issue is not always happened, sometimes it works fine.
And there is no issue, if I access any endpoints from the staging environment (using UBUNTU 16.04.7 LTS).
I'm using the KONG as the API Gateway (running as container in CentOS 7.9.2009 kong_server).

- KONG 2.0.1
- LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

All servers are using the same private network and the same private DNS server.
We've tried bypass our NGINX Proxy Server when the main domain accessing any endpoints (by using kong_server:xxxx).
Please advice me, if I need to provide more information to solve this issue.
Looking forward for the solution or any hints for this issue.
Thanks.

This is the log of the error.

```
A SocketError occurred in home#index:

  Failed to open TCP connection to kong_server:xxxx (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution)
  app/models/app.rb:4:in `search'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : http://main_domain.com/
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : x.x.x.x
  * Parameters : {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
  * Timestamp  : 2022-11-25 09:03:56 UTC
  * Server : app_server
    * Rails root : /app_directory_path/releases/20221124230456
  * Process: 56037

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary:
  
  ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `public_id' for "17a418e4db5e22d84ee5082d66525685":String
  Did you mean?  public_send
  
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:96:in `[]'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb:1:in `__app_directory_path_shared_bundle_ruby_______gems_exception_notification_______lib_exception_notifier_views_exception_notifier__session_text_erb___1259887619874614720_70094959924340'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:344:in `block in render_partial'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:333:in `render_partial'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:312:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:49:in `render_partial'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:36:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:9:in `block in __app_directory_path_shared_bundle_ruby_______gems_exception_notification_______lib_exception_notifier_views_exception_notifier_exception_notification_text_erb__3365026513843035604_70094968707260'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:7:in `map'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:7:in `__app_directory_path_shared_bundle_ruby_______gems_exception_notification_______lib_exception_notifier_views_exception_notifier_exception_notification_text_erb__3365026513843035604_70094968707260'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:919:in `block in collect_responses'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/collector.rb:28:in `custom'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb:11:in `text'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:136:in `block in compose_email'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:920:in `collect_responses'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:828:in `mail'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:135:in `compose_email'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:57:in `exception_notification'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:25:in `block in process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:17:in `handle_exceptions'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:24:in `process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:607:in `block in process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:606:in `process'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:123:in `block in processed_mailer'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:122:in `tap'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:122:in `processed_mailer'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionmailer-5.2.4.1/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:29:in `__getobj__'
  /home/baf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:80:in `method_missing'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:171:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier.rb:162:in `fire_notification'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier.rb:71:in `block in notify_exception'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier.rb:69:in `each'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notifier.rb:69:in `notify_exception'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:59:in `rescue in call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/exception_notification-4.4.3/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:48:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:17:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/head.rb:14:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:269:in `context'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:263:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.1.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
  /app_directory_path/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'

-------------------------------
Environment:
-------------------------------

  * GATEWAY_INTERFACE                                      : CGI/1.2
    * HTTP_ACCEPT                                            : text/html, application/xhtml+xml
    * HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING                                   : gzip, deflate, br
    * HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE                                   : en-US,en;q=0.9
    * HTTP_CONNECTION                                        : keep-alive
    * HTTP_COOKIE                                            : _ga=GA1.3.851066951.1664247544; _fbp=fb.2.1664247548458.1010494553; _rack-cas-app_session=17a418e4db5e22d84ee5082d66525685
    * HTTP_HOST                                              : main_domain.com
    * HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH                                     : W/"64a9d2514994c88c912210a97520c186"
    * HTTP_ORIGIN                                            : http://main_domain.com
    * HTTP_REFERER                                           : https://main_domain.com/approvals
    * HTTP_SEC_CH_UA                                         : "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
    * HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE                                  : ?0
    * HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM                                : "Windows"
    * HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST                                    : empty
    * HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE                                    : cors
    * HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE                                    : same-origin
    * HTTP_TURBOLINKS_REFERRER                               : https://main_domain.com/approvals
    * HTTP_USER_AGENT                                        : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    * HTTP_VERSION                                           : HTTP/1.1
    * HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR                                   : 10.0.y.y
    * ORIGINAL_FULLPATH                                      : /
    * ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME                                   :
    * PATH_INFO                                              : /
    * QUERY_STRING                                           :
    * REMOTE_ADDR                                            : x.x.x.x
    * REQUEST_METHOD                                         : GET
    * REQUEST_PATH                                           : /
    * REQUEST_URI                                            : /
    * ROUTES_47152330688340_SCRIPT_NAME                      :
    * SCRIPT_NAME                                            :
    * SERVER_NAME                                            : main_domain.com
    * SERVER_PORT                                            : 80
    * SERVER_PROTOCOL                                        : HTTP/1.1
    * SERVER_SOFTWARE                                        : puma 4.3.1 Mysterious Traveller
    * action_controller.instance                             : #<HomeController:0x00007f80820bf040>
    * action_dispatch.authenticated_encrypted_cookie_salt    : authenticated encrypted cookie
    * action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner                      : #<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x00007f808c109230>
    * action_dispatch.content_security_policy                :
    * action_dispatch.content_security_policy_nonce_generator:
    * action_dispatch.content_security_policy_report_only    : false
    * action_dispatch.cookies_digest                         :
    * action_dispatch.cookies_rotations                      : #<ActiveSupport::Messages::RotationConfiguration:0x000055c4ff8b6a68>
    * action_dispatch.cookies_serializer                     : json
    * action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_cipher                :
    * action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt                  : encrypted cookie
    * action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt           : signed encrypted cookie
    * action_dispatch.http_auth_salt                         : http authentication
    * action_dispatch.key_generator                          : #<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x000055c5048f55b0>
    * action_dispatch.logger                                 : #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000055c503ba0d60>
    * action_dispatch.parameter_filter                       : [:password]
    * action_dispatch.redirect_filter                        : []
    * action_dispatch.remote_ip                              : x.x.x.x
    * action_dispatch.request.accepts                        : [#<Mime::Type:0x000055c4fffb6908 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-2972404158444904653>]
    * action_dispatch.request.content_type                   :
    * action_dispatch.request.formats                        : [#<Mime::Type:0x000055c4fffb6908 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-2972404158444904653>]
    * action_dispatch.request.parameters                     : {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
    * action_dispatch.request.path_parameters                : {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
    * action_dispatch.request.query_parameters               : {}
    * action_dispatch.request.request_parameters             : {}
    * action_dispatch.request_id                             : 868e4282-a9e4-4c0d-bd32-5ef99c01229f
    * action_dispatch.routes                                 : #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000055c503d78ea8>
    * action_dispatch.secret_key_base                        : d810ddadf3d84fc677d85f1209a4e45aae8c4d69aa7f147795536b846c420ca886b0436d1e0da987e4296973069d552094eb3047e2cb2a7419fae21575b19cee
    * action_dispatch.secret_token                           :
    * action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions               : true
    * action_dispatch.show_exceptions                        : true
    * action_dispatch.signed_cookie_digest                   :
    * action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt                     : signed cookie
    * action_dispatch.use_authenticated_cookie_encryption    : true
    * puma.config                                            : #<Puma::Configuration:0x000055c4ff313340>
    * puma.request_body_wait                                 : 0
    * puma.socket                                            : #<TCPSocket:0x00007f80740b6e08>
    * rack.after_reply                                       : []
    * rack.errors                                            : #<IO:0x000055c4fe7d00c8>
    * rack.hijack                                            : #<Puma::Client:0x00007f80740b6de0>
    * rack.hijack?                                           : true
    * rack.input                                             : #<Puma::NullIO:0x000055c4fedd2c50>
    * rack.multiprocess                                      : false
    * rack.multithread                                       : true
    * rack.request.cookie_hash                               : {"_ga"=>"GA1.3.851066951.1664247544", "_fbp"=>"fb.2.1664247548458.1010494553", "_rack-cas-app_session"=>"17a418e4db5e22d84ee5082d66525685"}
    * rack.request.cookie_string                             : _ga=GA1.3.851066951.1664247544; _fbp=fb.2.1664247548458.1010494553; _rack-cas-app_session=17a418e4db5e22d84ee5082d66525685
    * rack.request.query_hash                                : {}
    * rack.request.query_string                              :
    * rack.run_once                                          : false
    * rack.session                                           : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x00007f8083c6c400>
    * rack.session.options                                   : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x00007f8083c6c388>
    * rack.tempfiles                                         : []
    * rack.url_scheme                                        : http
    * rack.version                                           : [1, 3]

-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  app/models/app.rb:4:in `search'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:14:in `index'
```

app.rb

```
class App
  class << self
    def search(keyword, limit, page, role_id = nil, ms_app_ids = nil)
      HTTParty.get(
        ROLE_API_URL + API_VERSION + '/apps/search',
        headers: HEADERS,
        verify: VERIFY,
        query: {
          keyword: keyword,
          limit: limit,
          page: page,
          role_id: role_id,
          ms_app_ids: ms_app_ids
        }
      ).parsed_response
    end

    def autocomplete(params, role_id = nil, ms_app_ids = nil)
      HTTParty.get(
        ROLE_API_URL + API_VERSION + '/apps/search',
        headers: HEADERS,
        verify: VERIFY,
        query: {
          keyword: params[:term],
          role_id: role_id,
          ms_app_ids: ms_app_ids
        }
      ).parsed_response
    end
  end
end
```

**update - 20221216**
We have tried call the endpoints directly, without KONG and we got the same error message.
Is it possible the issue on the HTTParty configuration or the HTTParty gem version?

Comment: What does your `search` method in `app/models/app.rb:4` look like? What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @spickermann please check the main post, I've updated the information. Thanks mate.

Comment: what request is coming to Kong and how kong is setup for the servicing this.

Comment: @Shaleen we deploy and run KONG as the container service. And for the request, is the post/put request to the each endpoints.

Any we have tried to call directly the endpoints (without KONG) and get the same error message.

Comment: if you are getting same error directly then it may be issue from the application (end point) which you are hosting. Looks like you need to resolve that first. May be you can update the question with more detail on how the end point is configured.

Comment: @Shaleen thanks for your replied. Could you give me the example of the endpoint configuration that you asked? I'm sorry don't really get it.

Currently we define this issue as known issue and we tell the users to refresh their browser (app page) when they get this issue. Because after they refresh/reload the page, they can access it.